# Web scrape to get Total Margin required for multi leg inputs

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, request

```
from requests import Session
BASE_URL = 'https://zerodha.com/margin-calculator/SPAN'
payload = {'action': 'calculate',
            'exchange[]': 'NFO',
            'product[]': 'FUT',
            'scrip[]': 'DHFL19AUG',
            'option_type[]': 'CE',
            'strike_price[]':120, 
            'qty[]': 4000,
            'trade[]': 'sell'
}

session = Session()
res = session.post(BASE_URL, data=payload)
data = res.json()
print(data)
```

this code works perfectly for single position, if i have multi leg position, which will have margin benifits, how to modify payload?

i am trying to get total margin required for spread,
ex: NIFTY 29JUN2023 18500CE sell and NIFTY 29JUN2023 18700CE buy,
the combined marging will be far less than sell leg